# Printing a chess table in php without using for loop

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I print a chess table in PHP without using for loops, is it possible to do it with conditional and logical statements only?

```
<table width = "270px" cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "0px" border = "1px" bordercolor = "gray"> 
<?php 
    $value = 0;

    for($col = 0; $col < 8; $col++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $value = $col;
    
        for($row = 0; $row < 8; $row++) {
            if($value%2 == 0) {
                echo
                "<td height=40px width=20px bgcolor=black></td>";
                $value++;
            }
            else {
                echo
                "<td height=40px width=20px bgcolor=white></td>";
                $value++;
            }
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Trivial answer is to add manually each row. A better solution involve iterations and `for` is a good choice.  `For` can be avoided with other loops maybe `while` or even some manual counters but all means the same thing : `iteration`. Maybe using an recursive algorithm to "avoid implicit loops", but the focal point it will be the same : `iteration`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use for loops?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `build-in loops` derived from some functions, here `array_walk`(only to avoid explicit `for`).But it the end the algorithm is the same. It's only a trick !

```
<?php 
$arr = array_fill(0,64,1);
array_walk($arr,"construct");
array_walk($arr,"display");
function construct(&$item, $key)
{
    $color=$key%2;
    
    $i=($key-$key%8)/8 + 1;
    if($i%2==0)
        $color = ($color+1)%2;
    $color = $color%2==0 ? "white" : "black";
    $j=$key%8+1;
    $item = new Square($i,$j,$color);
}
function display($item, $key)
{
    if($key%8==0) echo "<br>";
    echo $item." ";
    
}

class Square
{
    public $i;
    public $j;
    public $color;
    public function __construct($i,$j,$color)
    {
        $this->i=$i;
        $this->j=$j;
        $this->color=$color;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "[".$this->i.",".$this->j."]=".($this->color);
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
[1,1]=white [1,2]=black [1,3]=white [1,4]=black [1,5]=white [1,6]=black [1,7]=white [1,8]=black
[2,1]=black [2,2]=white [2,3]=black [2,4]=white [2,5]=black [2,6]=white [2,7]=black [2,8]=white
[3,1]=white [3,2]=black [3,3]=white [3,4]=black [3,5]=white [3,6]=black [3,7]=white [3,8]=black
[4,1]=black [4,2]=white [4,3]=black [4,4]=white [4,5]=black [4,6]=white [4,7]=black [4,8]=white
[5,1]=white [5,2]=black [5,3]=white [5,4]=black [5,5]=white [5,6]=black [5,7]=white [5,8]=black
[6,1]=black [6,2]=white [6,3]=black [6,4]=white [6,5]=black [6,6]=white [6,7]=black [6,8]=white
[7,1]=white [7,2]=black [7,3]=white [7,4]=black [7,5]=white [7,6]=black [7,7]=white [7,8]=black
[8,1]=black [8,2]=white [8,3]=black [8,4]=white [8,5]=black [8,6]=white [8,7]=black [8,8]=white
```

For html grid, just adapt `display`.

```
function displayHtml($item, $key)
{
    if($item->i==1 && $item->j==1)
        echo '<table width="270px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1px" bordercolor="gray">';
    if($item->j%8==1)
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td height=40px width=20px style='background-color:".$item->color."'></td>";
    if($item->j%8==0)
        echo "</tr>";
    if($item->i==8 && $item->j==8)
        echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_repeat`:

```
<table width="270px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1px" bordercolor="gray"> 
<?php 
$td = '<td height="40px" width="20px" bgcolor=';
$black = "$td'black'></td>";
$white = "$td'white'></td>";
echo str_repeat("<tr>" . str_repeat($black . $white, 4) . "</tr><tr>" 
                       . str_repeat($white . $black, 4) . "</tr>", 4);
?>
</table>
```